# nhibernate difficulty in save

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nhibernate, razor

i have this the code and i have this problem

- i am trying to save a new user to my web site : the query is succeded but without insertion
- ie the table "User" and the table "UserAcl" still without any modification and it is clear that the query is executed 
  File User.cs:

File Compte.cs

```
public bool SaveUser(string identification, string acc, string mot, string notify, string nom, string phone, string mail) {
               try
               {
                   if (identification == null || acc == null || nom == null || mail == null  || mot == null) return false;
                   ITransaction transaction = User.OpenSession().BeginTransaction();
                   User u = new User() { Account = acc, Identification = identification, ContactEmail = mail, ContactName = nom, ContactPhone = phone, NotifyEmail = notify, Password = mot };
                   User.OpenSession().SaveOrUpdate(u);
                   transaction.Commit();
                  ITransaction transaction2 = User.OpenSession().BeginTransaction();
                   Useracl ua = new Useracl { Account = acc, UserID = identification, AccessLevel = 1, AclID = (Useracl.GetUseracl().Count + 1).ToString() };
                   Useracl.OpenSession().SaveOrUpdate(ua);
                   transaction2.Commit();
                   return true;
               }
               catch { return false; }

           }
```

File Administration.cs

```
  public ActionResult Index()
       {

           ViewBag.Title = c.GetUserID().Count.ToString();
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult BeforeRegister()
        {


            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult AfterRegister(string Pseudo, string Phone, string Email, string Password, string Notify)
        {

            bool a = c.SaveUser((c.GetPassword().Count + 1).ToString(), (c.GetPassword().Count + 1).ToString(), Password, Notify, Pseudo, Phone, Email);
            if (a)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Administration");
            }
            else

                return RedirectToAction("BeforeRegister", "Administration");

        }
```

Comment: It looks like you are opening multiple sessions with each call to User.OpenSession(), so you are starting a transaction on one session, and saving the user in another session and then committing the transaction for the first session and never doing anything with the second session, and then repeating this the next time.. the answer below gives a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could use `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(myString))` rather than `if (myString==null)`.
Also, you may want to use your sessions within a `using` block.

```
bool ret= new bool();
if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(foo1)) && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(foo2)))
{
//ConnectionDB is a public class, with a static method ISessionFactory SessionFactory(), and the method OpenSession() returns an ISession 
 using (NHibernate.ISession nhSession = ConnectionDB.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
 {
 try
 {
  User u = new User();
  //set your User
  nhSession.Transaction.Begin();
  nhSession.Save(u);
  nhSession.Transaction.Commit();
  nhSession.Close();

  ret = true;
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 ret = false;
 }
}
return ret;
```

Now, about the query not inserting, it could be a mapping problem, or maybe you're supressing the exception elsewhere (like your static method `User.OpenSession().SaveOrUpdate(u)`)